# Determining whether or not a set contains an element, and proving set equalities.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have two problems that are giving me a bit of a difficulty. I've already completed one of them, but I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong, and would greatly appreciate feedback. For the other one, I'm lost entirely.

```
For each of the following sets, determine whether 4 is an element of that set.

a) {x ∈ R | x is an integer greater than 4}

b) {x ∈ R | x is the square of an integer|

c) {4,{4}}

d) {{4},{{4}}}

e) {{4},{4,{4}}}

f) {{{4}}}
```

I answered as the following:

a. As x is greater than 4, 4 is not in the set.

b. If the integer is 2, the square of 2 is 4, meaning that 4 is an element of the set. (Truthfully, I'm on the fence about this. How do I know that the square is 2?)

c. The set contains the value 4, and the subset {4}. 4 is in the set.

d. The set contains the subsets {4} and {{4}}. 4 is not an element in the set. (I assume that {4} isn't the same as 4)

e. The set contains the subset {4} and {4,{4}}. 4 is an element of the subset, but not the set.

f. The set consists wholly of the subset {{{4}}}. 4 is not an element.

The second problem I'm lost on completely is

```
Prove or disprove:
A - (B n C) = (A-B) u (A-C)
```

I know that A is equivalent to (A u A), so I can go from

A- (B n C) = (A-B) u (A-C)
   (A u A) - (B n C) = (A-B) u (A-C)

But from there, I'm lost. I don't even know how A-B or A-C would translate into anything else, so any assistance would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic in 1 is fine.  For part 2,  to prove two sets are equal, show they are subsets of each other.
So, assume $x\in A-(B\cap C)$  Xo,  $x\in A$  and $x\notin (B\cap C)$  Thus,  we have $x\notin B$ or $x\notin C$ along with $x\in A$.  thus,  we have $x\in A-B$ or $x\in A-C$
Hence, $x\in (A-B)\cup(A-C)$

To argue the reverse, just start with an element of the right hand side and follow the same logic backward to the left hand side

Answer (score 1):

For your set equality,
draw a Venn diagram with
circles for A, B, and C.
You can then visually see
what the two sides are
and why they are equal.